# Mysql triggers and insert values

Tags: php, mysql

I try to set a trigger before I insert a value into table `ec3_checking`, the trigger's function is set 'account_id' to 'CH-n' if the highest value for id_count is (n-1), id_count is an auto_increment parameter.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER account_id_add BEFORE INSERT ON `ec3_checking`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        DECLARE anum int;
        DECLARE bnum int;
        SET bnum =  max(id_account);
        SET anum = bnum + 1;
        SET NEW.account_id =  concat('CH-', anum);
END//
```

Then I try to insert some values into the table

```
insert into `ec3_checking` (balance, overdraft_limit)
VALUES
('300','50');
```

There is an error:1111, invalid use of group function, could anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `account_id_add` BEFORE INSERT ON `ec3_checking` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE anum int;

    SET @bnum = (SELECT max(id_account) FROM ec3_checking);

    SET anum = @bnum + 1;
    SET NEW.account_name =  concat('CH-', anum);
END
```

Comment: Thanks @XueweiFan. Please don't forget to upvote and to flag it as the correct answer. I would appreciate it :)